# Resource for TableDef field type integers in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to find a resource to tie the field type integers I'm receiving from the following:

```
    MsgBox CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblTemp").Fields("ID").Type
```

to their corresponding data types.  Here's an example from Office Dev Center, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845405(v=office.14).aspx

but this is the properties list for the 'Field' collection instead of 'Fields'.  The integers I'm returning are coming from somewhere... Autonumber returns 4, DateTime 8, Text 10, Memo 12, it's working so I assume they're cataloged somewhere.  Might be the result of another reference library I have active, only Office and Excel Objects outside of the norm for Access.

Does anyone have any ideas on a resource I can utilize, or maybe an explanation if I'm misinterpreting these values?

Comment: `.Type` gives you `dbLong` (Long Integer) for an autonumber field.  You can check the autonumber field's attributes to determine it is not just a plain Long Integer field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values returned by `.Type` are members of the `DAO.DataTypeEnum`.

```
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("id").Type
 4 
? dbLong
 4
```

You can use the Object Browser from the VB Editor to look up the names and values of those enum members.

[image: Object Browser displaying DAO.DataTypeEnum]

Comment: You're welcome.  I also like that Allen Browne function you linked, and have used it in the past.  However I wasn't sure whether you actually needed it for this.  In any case, it's good to remember the Object Browser because it's so convenient.

Answer (score 2):

http://allenbrowne.com/func-06.html

Found this almost immediately after submitting this question, while I had googled for over an hour prior its submission.  Guess that's how it goes...  It's for Access 2000-02, but seems to correspond to the values I'm receiving.  Posting for future researchers.